# Grouping and ordering at one level, showing counts on another

Tags: python, pandas

For the example below

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio',
                  'Nevada', 'Nevada','Nevada','Nevada'],
        'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2002, 2002,
                 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002],
        'pop': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output

```
   pop   state  year
0    1    Ohio  2000
1    1    Ohio  2000
2    1    Ohio  2000
3    1    Ohio  2002
4    1    Ohio  2002
5    1  Nevada  2002
6    1  Nevada  2002
7    1  Nevada  2002
8    1  Nevada  2002
```

I need sums on pop, for each state + year combination, *however*, sorting needs to be based on state level.

So I need counts within counts, with ordering done on first level. The output is like

```
  state  year  sum
   Ohio  2000  3
         2002  2
   Nev.  2002  4
```

As you see Ohio is on top, because with sum 5 its total group has more items.

The display is key, I would  like to show state Ohio only once.

I believe I need to use hierarchical indexes on Pandas, however I could not figure out the exact syntax. Can stack / unstack be useful here?

Comment: What happened to Nevada 2001?  Could you edit to include exactly the output you want?

Answer (score 4):

`stack()` and `unstack()` *can* help, yes, plus `reindex()`:

```
In [11]: res = df.groupby(['state', 'year']).sum()

In [12]: res
Out[12]: 
             pop
state  year     
Nevada 2001    1
       2002    3
Ohio   2000    3
       2002    2

In [13]: st = np.sort(df.groupby('state')['pop'].sum())[::-1]

In [14]: st
Out[14]: 
state
Ohio      5
Nevada    4
Name: pop

In [15]: res.unstack().reindex(st.index).stack()
Out[15]: 
             pop
state  year     
Ohio   2000    3
       2002    2
Nevada 2001    1
       2002    3
```

although I'm not sure if it's the most elegant solution. I'd let `pandas` kung-fu masters to say their words of wisdom here.